# Api call is not working in React native cli

Tags: reactjs, react-native

no error is coming in catch block, the same code works on expo and react js, however not working on react native cli

The following is my code snippet:

```
async onPressButton() {
    let data = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            number: this.state.phone
        }),
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    }

    this.setState({
        isLoading: true
    })
    console.log('phone', this.state.phone);
    try{
        console.log('data', data);
     const resposne = await fetch('http://atiiuserauth.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/verify/mobile/', data)
     console.log('ress', resposne.json());
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Install Wireshark and see what goes over the wire.

Comment: resposne.json() should be response.json()

Comment: I tried everything, even after checking the compilation error, it did not work, hence I recreated the project with expo-cli and then ran npm run-eject to eject it to react native, and thereby it started working